# cake php tree model join tables

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have three tables: `books`, `books_categories` and `categories`.

```
books:
   ...

categories:
    id, name, parent_id

books_categories:
    id book_id category_id
```

So one book might be in many categories and one category might have many books.
And categories are a tree - each category has parent (or `NULL`) (and virtually children).
The problem is that if we have categories: `a` > `b` > `c` and book belongs to category `a`, it doesnt mean that it belongs to subcategories `b` or `c`... And I want to get all books from category `a` even from subcategories.

For now I get all books from specified category like this:

```
$options['joins'] = array(    
                array('table' => 'books_categories',
                      'alias' => 'BookCategory',
                      'type' => 'inner', 
                      'conditions' => array('Book.id = BookCategory.book_id')
                ),
                array('table' => 'categories',
                      'alias' => 'Category',
                      'type' => 'inner',
                      'conditions' => array('BookCategory.category_id = Category.id')
               ));

               $options['conditions'] = array('Category.id' => '5');


$this->set('books', $this->Book->find('all', $options));
```

And this correctly finds all books from category of `id = '5'`. And I need also books from child categories of '5' - is it possible in single query? Or I have to get all parent child categories (how) and then in conditions set `'Category.id' => '5' OR 'Category.id => '6'` and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$allCategories = $this->Book->find('threaded');
```

Comment: @user606521 if you set up your categories to have parents or associations between each other then it just might help. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-find-threaded